# jQuery/Ajax - Redirect to another page after succes message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to redirect the user after filling up the contact form and the success message appears.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="wpm_download_1" style="display: inline;">
   The link to the file(s) has been emailed to you.
</div>
```

and here's the JavaScript I'm trying:

```
function() { 
      var isDownloaded = jQuery('#wpm_download_1').text(); 
        if (typeof obj.isDownloaded != 'undefined'){
            window.location = 'http://google.com';
        }

    }
```

Basically, I want to redirect the user when this message appears after sending form data through `AJAX`:

The link to the file(s) has been emailed to you..

Comment: Not a complete picture there. Are you having problems with that?

Comment: You need to initiate your function. Right now it just exists. You should give your function a name and then call it somewhere `function myFunction(){};` and then call it later `myFunction();`

Comment: `isDownloaded` is necessarily a string (you ask for `.text()` ). `obj.isDownloaded` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after trying hard I just came up this and it worked:

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
});
```

Becuase, I wanted to be redirected after the [successful AJAX request](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use obj.isDownloaded ? 
Here it works :

```
 jQuery('#wpm_download_1').text(); 
 if (typeof isDownloaded != 'undefined'){
   window.location = 'http://google.com';
 }
```

Is up to you to call the function whenever you need it

Answer (score 0):

Before, you must call your function. And for redirect please which one method below:

window.location.href example:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.
```

window.open() example:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new window.
```